# A more elegant approach to multiple checks performed in java class?

Tags: java

I have the below conditions to check which I will be checking based on the value that I will be recieving on parameter incomingProduct, So, I have below multiple conditions but they look odd as every time multiple checks wil be performed please advise how can i customise the below checks with else if I can acheive the same thing.

```
String incomingProduct = wokerchoice.getProduct();

  if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("CD") ) {
  wokerchoice.setFourceSystem
  ((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("CD"));
  }

  if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("MODITY") ) {
     wokerchoice.setFourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("MODITY"));
  }

  if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("WQEQD") ) {
     wokerchoice.setFourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("WEREQD"));
  }

  if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("QRTFI") ) {
     wokerchoice.setFourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("WERFI"));
  }  

  if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("URES") ) {
     wokerchoice.setFourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("V"));
  }  

  if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("FXQWNM") ) {
     wokerchoice.setFourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("FXQWNM"));
  }

  if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("IERTRD") ) {
     wokerchoice.setFourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("IERTRD"));
  }

  if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("UHVMM") ) {
     wokerchoice.setFourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get(UHV"MM"));
  }

  if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("OPT") ) {
     wokerchoice.setFourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("OPT"));
  }

  if (incomingProduct!= null &&  incomingProduct.equalsIgnoreCase("RECE") ) {
     wokerchoice.setFourceSystem((String)configuration.getConfiguration().get("RECS"));
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Since yours aren't the same, the usual thing to do is to put the incoming and outgoing mappings on a map:

```
Map<String, String> ht = new HashMap<String, String>(){ { put("ONE","ONE"); 
put("OTHER","TWO");} };

String cfg = ht.get(incomingProduct.toUpperCase());
if (cfg != null)
    wokerchoice.setFourceSystem((String)configuration
    .getConfiguration().get(cfg));
```

Sadly java doesn't yet give us the ability to declare literal maps so I used the ugly anonymous class hack you see above to get a one liner.

If you could get the incoming and outgoing mappings the same (which I recommend, though it might not be possible), you could use a list or array of strings instead.

```
String[] mapping = {"ONE", "TWO"};
String incoming = incomingProduct.toUpperCase();
if(Arrays.asList(mapping).contains(incoming)){
 wokerchoice.setFourceSystem((String)configuration
        .getConfiguration().get(incoming));
}
```

But really; assuming getConfiguration().get() returns a null if there is no value (and you can get rid if the mapping step), the best answer looks something like so:

```
String incoming = incomingProduct.toUpperCase(); 
Object cfg= configuration.getConfiguration().get(incoming);
If (cfg != null)
    wokerchoice.setFourceSystem((String)cfg);
```

Comment: I would *prefer* the [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface (and [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) implementation) to `Hashtable`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you please advise your earlier approach of Array please